# How to use relative_url_root on internal page link in Alchemy CMS

Tags: hyperlink, relative-url, alchemy-cms

I have my own root url as: `http://localhost:9292/myownsite/`.
In a EssenceRichtext textbox, I would like to link a internal page to some string, like page-url in its AlchemyPage.urlname. But the link displays `localhost:9292/page-url` instead of `localhost:9292/myownsite/page-url`.

How to add this relative url root on?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the link plugin. Could you open a issue on GitHub?

Comment: Reported on GitHub